# Search Ipython notebook in Pycharm?

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm

I'm using Ipython in Pycharm. Is there a way to seach the entire notebook?

**Update**: ctrl+shift+F only shows search result. Double clicking on the result doesn't lead the cursor jump to the line of code. Anyone would like to shed some light?

Comment: Does `Ctrl+Shift+F` (find in path) work (I haven't actually used notebooks in pycharm and can't test this out at the moment)?

Comment: Hi Bahorm, Ctrl+Shift+F searches for all files under path. Is there a way to search within the current Ipython notebook?

Comment: You could limit it to your notebook path perhaps?

Comment: Hi Bahorm, thanks! That works. But when I double click the record, it doesn't jump to the line automatically...in .py file, double click to preview moves to the line of interest.

Comment: This question is better meant for [su] than [so].